# Add language support files for validationengine jquery dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I am using validationengine jquery for validation in ASP.NET application. I want to add language support files dynamically from code behind or using java script.I have tried the following way:

In master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       loadjscssfile("Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js");
    });

    function loadjscssfile(filename) {
            var fileref = document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);

            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
        }
</script>
```

In child page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(formid).validationEngine('attach');
    });
</script>
```

The language file is loaded dynamically, but it is attached to validationEngine jquery only when alert() statement is written after loadjscsssfile() statement. If alert() statement is commented, it gives error 'Plz add validationEngine language rules'.

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524881/validationengine-jquery-not-working-properly-for-localization/14526668#14526668) from you 2 days ago. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius I tried your solution, but it is giving error 'Plz add validationengine language rules'.

Comment: @Fuex I have tried the following soltion:    $(document).ready(function () {                
   var lang = $('#HdfLanguage').val();
   if (lang == "en-US") 
      loadjscssfile("Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js");
   else 
      loadjscssfile("Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-ja.js");
                                                                       $("#form1").validationEngine({ showOneMessage: false, scroll: false, promptPosition: "topCenter", focusFirstField: false });
                
            });